# Text input instead of select using OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

How to set text input in form instead of select (choice) which is automatically generated in Symfony when I'm using ManyToOne and OneToMany mapping? I would like to be able to fill input field manually and not select it from the list.
Is it possible to set is like this and then change somehow the mapping?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(new Record())
    ->add('foreign_id', 'text')
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: Try with `->add('foreign_id', 'integer')`

Answer (score 0):

You must use a Symfony Form Transformer, when can transform object to scalar or another data for view in input (textfield for example), and reverse transformation for load object from scalar value.

For more information please see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

**UPD:** the field can be any type, if you use data transformer for this field.